# Calling Method after Initialize Component

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms application that follows the MVVM pattern, and I want to call an Splash Page on the Main Page constructor, I have the Navigation Command, just don't know how to call it.

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new ViewModel.MainPageViewModel();
            //here I would like to Call the SplashCommand
        }
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
public MainPageViewModel()
        {

            this.SplashCommand = new Command(this.MethodThatNavigatesToSplashPage);
            this._navigationService = DependencyService.Get<Service.INavigationService>();
        }
```

Comment: splash page as in a page which gets displayed for some seconds and then the application starts is that what u mean to say ?

Comment: Yes, but I'm doing it by just calling the splash page on the Navigation by PushModalAsync, then, in the Splash Page, I have a method that closes the page and returns to the MainPage(after 3 seconds).

Comment: but why do u need to do so you can call your splash screen from main activity.

Comment: Does the splash screen really need to be a `Command`? Perhaps within App.xaml.cs or whichever be the application startup you can call Splash code followed by code to display main window. But if what you are referring to is a notification instead of splash screen, then it would be a different deal.

Comment: I tried to call it from the main activity, but then the rest of the navigatoin didn't worked, but, I'll try it that way again.

Comment: here is reference link https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-splash-screen-xamarin-forms/ u can get the splash screen and if u need any animation on it then u need to used lottie

Comment: You're much better off doing this natively. Sooner or later you're going to run into the problem where the Xamarin/.NET startup code...which needs to be executed before your splash screen is made visible...starts becoming uncomfortably long. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen) shows how to do it for Android and [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens) shows how to do it for iOS.